# Search for string in files changed on git branch

Tags: git, grep

I want to search for a string in a file that I have changed on a git branch, but it's in a line that I *haven't* changed. How can I do that reliably?

Comment: How can the string change if the line it is on didn't change?

Comment: The string didn't change. The file did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in bash shell (on Windows, make sure you are using "Git bash" or WSL, not "Git CMD").

Let's call the branch you branched off from `develop`. Replace `develop` with the name of the actual branch you branched off this branch from, and `search_string` with your actual search string, below.

```
git checkout branch_name
git diff --name-only develop... | xargs grep 'search_string'
```

Note the *three* dots! This will ignore changes in develop since you branched off, so it will just compare with the commit you branched it off from.